# xpath_element in deployed Shiny App error

Tags: r, xpath, shiny, rvest

Like many other people, I'm having some issues with the `html_nodes()` function in the `rvest` package. I've made a Shiny app that goes onto a publicly available data website and scrapes it to find the url of the most recently posted dataset which is always a .csv file. My app works perfectly when I use it locally, but when I try to deploy it to Shinyapps.io, I receive the following error message:

```
Error : could not find function "xpath_element"
```

After doing some digging, it seems like some people have suggested loading the newer/newest versions of R, which I did. And others have suggested explicitly loading the `selectr` package, which I have also done. Still others suggested explicitly stating the css/xpath choice in `html_nodes()`.  I've tried all of these to no avail. Am I misinterpreting the `rvest` package and syntax incorrectly or are there other forces at work here that I'm not grasping?

Here's my code and a million thanks in advance:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(selectr)

epa.data.page <- read_html("https://www.epa.gov/fuels-registration-reporting-and-compliance-help/spreadsheet-rin-generation-and-renewable-fuel")
epa.csv.page <- paste0("https://www.epa.gov",
  epa.data.page %>%
  html_nodes(css = "a") %>%       # find all links
  html_attr("href") %>%     # get the url
  str_subset("\\.csv") %>%
  .[[1]])                # look at the first one

epa.data.date <-
  epa.data.page %>%
  html_nodes(css = ".fileinfo") %>%
  html_text()

last.update <- word(epa.data.date[1], -2:-1)
last.update <- paste(last.update[1], last.update[2])
last.update <- substr(last.update, 1, (nchar(last.update)-1))

rindata <- read.csv(url(epa.csv.page))
rindata$rin.date <- as.Date(paste0(rindata$RIN.Year,"-",rindata$Production.Month,"-01"))
rindata$Fuel.Code <- as.factor(rindata$Fuel.Code)

rin.melt <- melt(rindata, .(Fuel.Code, RIN.Year, Production.Month, rin.date), .(RIN.Quantity, Batch.Volume), variable.name = "rf.metric")

tol12qualitative <- c("#332288", "#6699CC", "#88CCEE", "#44AA99", "#117733", "#999933", "#DDCC77", "#661100", "#CC6677", "#AA4466", "#882255", "#AA4499")
col.usa <- c("#0071bc", "#205493", "#323a45", "#aeb0b5", "#02bfe7", "#046b99", "#9bdaf1", "#e31c3d", "#981b1e", "#e59393", "#fdb81e", "#2e8540")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("RIN Generation and Fuel Production by Month"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeInput("rfs.period", "Date Range:", 
                     start = "2010-07-01",
                     end = as.Date(paste0(max(rindata$RIN.Year), "-", 
                                  max(rindata$Production.Month[rindata$RIN.Year == max(rindata$RIN.Year)]), "-01")),
                     min = "2010-07-01",
                     max = paste0(max(rindata$RIN.Year), "-", 
                                  max(rindata$Production.Month[rindata$RIN.Year == max(rindata$RIN.Year)]), "-01"),
                     format = "MM d, yyyy",
                     startview = "decade"),
      fluidRow(column(6, checkboxGroupInput("fuel.type", "D-Code:", 
                         choices = c("D3" = "3", "D4" = "4", "D5" = "5", "D6" = "6", "D7" = "7"),
                         selected = c("D6" = "6"))), 
               column(6, radioButtons("metric.type", "Plot Type:",
                                      choices = c("RIN Quantity" = "RIN.Quantity", 
                                                  "Batch Volume" = "Batch.Volume",
                                                  "Both" = "dual.plot"),
                                      selected = c("Both" = "dual.plot")),
                      checkboxInput("scale_y", "Scale Y-Axis", value = FALSE))),
      uiOutput("ringen.message"),
      br(),
      a("Download this Data", href = epa.csv.page),
      br(),
      a("Contact Administrator", href="mailto:furlong.kyle@epa.gov"),
      br(),
      br(),
      paste0("Date current as of ", last.update, ".")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("rin.plot")
    ),
    position = "left"
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$ringen.message <- renderUI({
    if (input$metric.type != "Batch.Volume"){
      tagList("Note: RINs are generated when a gallon of renewable fuel is produced. The quantity of RINs generated is determined by that fuel's Equivalence Value (EV). For more information,", a("read the regualtion defining this process", href = "https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div6&node=40:17.0.1.1.9.13#se40.19.80_11415"))
    }
    else
      return()
  })

  title.text <- reactive({
    if (input$metric.type == "dual.plot"){
      if ( (months(input$rfs.period[1])==months(input$rfs.period[2])) && 
           (year(input$rfs.period[1])==year(input$rfs.period[2])) ){
        paste("Reported Generation and Production,", months(input$rfs.period[1]), year(input$rfs.period[1]))
      }
      else
        paste("Reported Generation and Production,", months(input$rfs.period[1]), year(input$rfs.period[1]), "-", months(input$rfs.period[2]), year(input$rfs.period[2]))
    }
    else{
      if (input$metric.type == "RIN.Quantity"){
        if ( (months(input$rfs.period[1])==months(input$rfs.period[2])) && 
           (year(input$rfs.period[1])==year(input$rfs.period[2])) ){
          paste("Reported RIN Generation,", months(input$rfs.period[1]), year(input$rfs.period[1]))
        }
        else
          paste("Reported RIN Generation,", months(input$rfs.period[1]), year(input$rfs.period[1]), "-", months(input$rfs.period[2]), year(input$rfs.period[2]))
      }
      else{
        if ( (months(input$rfs.period[1])==months(input$rfs.period[2])) && 
             (year(input$rfs.period[1])==year(input$rfs.period[2])) ){
          paste("Reported Fuel Production,", months(input$rfs.period[1]), year(input$rfs.period[1]))
        }
        else
          paste("Reported Fuel Production,", months(input$rfs.period[1]), year(input$rfs.period[1]), "-", months(input$rfs.period[2]), year(input$rfs.period[2]))
        }
      }
    })

  output$rin.plot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(input$scale_y) || input$scale_y==FALSE){
      if (input$metric.type != "dual.plot"){
        if ( (months(input$rfs.period[1])==months(input$rfs.period[2])) && 
             (year(input$rfs.period[1])==year(input$rfs.period[2]))){
          rf.rin.plot <- ggplot(data = rindata[which(rindata$rin.date %in% input$rfs.period[1]:input$rfs.period[2] &
                                                 rindata$Fuel.Code %in% input$fuel.type),]) + 
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = Fuel.Code, y = rindata[rindata$rin.date %in% input$rfs.period[1]:input$rfs.period[2] &
                                                                     rindata$Fuel.Code %in% input$fuel.type, 
                                                                   input$metric.type]/1000000, fill = Fuel.Code)) + 
            labs(x = "", y = ifelse(input$metric.type == "RIN.Quantity", "RINs (Millions)", "Renewable Fuel (Million Gallons)"), title = title.text()) +
            coord_flip() + theme(legend.position = "") + 
            scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),
                              labels = c("D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7"), 
                              values = tol12qualitative[1:length(input$fuel.type)])+
            guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))
        }
        else{
          rf.rin.plot <- ggplot(data = rindata[which(rindata$rin.date %in% floor_date(input$rfs.period[1], unit = "month"):input$rfs.period[2] &
                                               rindata$Fuel.Code %in% input$fuel.type),]) +
          geom_line(aes(x = rin.date, y = rindata[which(rindata$rin.date %in% floor_date(input$rfs.period[1], unit = "month"):input$rfs.period[2] &
                                                    rindata$Fuel.Code %in% input$fuel.type), 
                                                  input$metric.type]/1000000, color = Fuel.Code)) + 
          labs(x = "", y = ifelse(input$metric.type == "RIN.Quantity", "RINs (Millions)", "Renewable Fuel (Million Gallons)"), title = title.text()) + 
            scale_color_manual(name = "D-Code",
                               breaks = c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), 
                               labels = c("D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7"),
                               values = tol12qualitative[1:length(input$fuel.type)])+
            guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))
          }
        print(rf.rin.plot)
        }
     else{
       if ( (months(input$rfs.period[1])==months(input$rfs.period[2])) && 
           (year(input$rfs.period[1])==year(input$rfs.period[2]))){

          rf.rin.plot2 <- ggplot(data = rin.melt[which(rin.melt$rin.date %in% input$rfs.period[1]:input$rfs.period[2] &
                                                 rin.melt$Fuel.Code %in% input$fuel.type),]) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = interaction(Fuel.Code, rf.metric), y = value/1000000, fill = Fuel.Code)) + 
          labs(x = "", y = "Quantity (Millions)", title = title.text()) +
          coord_flip() + theme(legend.position = "") + 
          scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("3.RIN.Quantity", "4.RIN.Quantity", "5.RIN.Quantity", "6.RIN.Quantity", "7.RIN.Quantity", "3.Batch.Volume", "4.Batch.Volume", "5.Batch.Volume", "6.Batch.Volume", "7.Batch.Volume"),
                           labels = c("D3 RINs", "D4 RINs", "D5 RINs", "D6 RINs", "D7 RINs", "D3 Batch Volume", "D4 Batch Volume", "D5 Batch Volume", "D6 Batch Volume", "D7 Batch Volume")) + 
            scale_fill_manual(values = tol12qualitative[1:length(input$fuel.type)])+
            guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))
      }
      else{
          rf.rin.plot2 <- ggplot(data = rin.melt[rin.melt$rin.date %in% floor_date(input$rfs.period[1], unit = "month"):input$rfs.period[2] &
                                                 rin.melt$Fuel.Code %in% input$fuel.type,]) + 
          geom_line(aes(x = rin.date, y = value/1000000,  color = interaction(Fuel.Code, rf.metric))) + 
          labs(x = "", y = "Quantity (Millions)", title = title.text()) + 
            scale_color_manual(name = "D-Code", 
                               breaks = c("3.RIN.Quantity", "4.RIN.Quantity", "5.RIN.Quantity", "6.RIN.Quantity", "7.RIN.Quantity", "3.Batch.Volume", "4.Batch.Volume", "5.Batch.Volume", "6.Batch.Volume", "7.Batch.Volume"),
                               labels = c("D3 RINs", "D4 RINs", "D5 RINs", "D6 RINs", "D7 RINs", "D3 Batch Volume", "D4 Batch Volume", "D5 Batch Volume", "D6 Batch Volume", "D7 Batch Volume"),
                               values = tol12qualitative[1:(2*length(input$fuel.type))])+
            guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))
        }
       print(rf.rin.plot2)
     }
    }
    else{
      if (input$metric.type != "dual.plot"){
        if ( (months(input$rfs.period[1])==months(input$rfs.period[2])) && 
             (year(input$rfs.period[1])==year(input$rfs.period[2]))){
          rf.rin.plot <- ggplot(data = rindata[rindata$rin.date %in% input$rfs.period[1]:input$rfs.period[2] &
                                                 rindata$Fuel.Code %in% input$fuel.type,]) + 
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = Fuel.Code, y = rindata[rindata$rin.date %in% input$rfs.period[1]:input$rfs.period[2] &
                                                                         rindata$Fuel.Code %in% input$fuel.type, 
                                                                       input$metric.type]/1000000, fill = Fuel.Code)) + 
            labs(x = "", y = ifelse(input$metric.type == "RIN.Quantity", "RINs (Millions)", "Renewable Fuel (Million Gallons)"), title = title.text()) +
            coord_flip() + theme(legend.position = "", strip.text.x = element_blank()) + 
            scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),
                              labels = c("D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7"), 
                              values = tol12qualitative[1:length(input$fuel.type)])+
            guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3))) 
        }
        else{
          rf.rin.plot <- ggplot(data = rin.melt[rin.melt$Fuel.Code %in% input$fuel.type &
                                                  rin.melt$rin.date %in% floor_date(input$rfs.period[1], unit = "month"):input$rfs.period[2] &
                                                  rin.melt$rf.metric == input$metric.type,]) +
            geom_line(aes(x = rin.date, y = value/1000000, color = Fuel.Code)) + 
            facet_wrap(~Fuel.Code!=6, nrow = 2, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
            labs(x = "", y = ifelse(input$metric.type == "RIN.Quantity", "RINs (Millions)", "Renewable Fuel (Million Gallons)"), title = title.text()) +
            scale_color_manual(name = "D-Code",
                               breaks = c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), 
                               labels = c("D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7"),
                               values = tol12qualitative[1:length(input$fuel.type)]) +  
            guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3))) +
            theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())
          }
        print(rf.rin.plot)
      }

    else{
      if ( (months(input$rfs.period[1])==months(input$rfs.period[2])) && 
           (year(input$rfs.period[1])==year(input$rfs.period[2]))){

        rf.rin.plot2 <- ggplot(data = rin.melt[rin.melt$rin.date %in% input$rfs.period[1]:input$rfs.period[2] &
                                                 rin.melt$Fuel.Code %in% input$fuel.type,]) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = interaction(Fuel.Code, rf.metric), y = value/1000000, fill = Fuel.Code)) + 
          labs(x = "", y = "Quantity (Millions)", title = title.text()) +
          coord_flip() + theme(legend.position = "", strip.text.x = element_blank()) + 
          scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("3.RIN.Quantity", "4.RIN.Quantity", "5.RIN.Quantity", "6.RIN.Quantity", "7.RIN.Quantity", "3.Batch.Volume", "4.Batch.Volume", "5.Batch.Volume", "6.Batch.Volume", "7.Batch.Volume"),
                           labels = c("D3 RINs", "D4 RINs", "D5 RINs", "D6 RINs", "D7 RINs", "D3 Batch Volume", "D4 Batch Volume", "D5 Batch Volume", "D6 Batch Volume", "D7 Batch Volume")) + 
          scale_fill_manual(values = tol12qualitative[1:length(input$fuel.type)])+
          guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3))) 
      }
      else{
        rf.rin.plot2 <- ggplot(data = rin.melt[rin.melt$rin.date %in% floor_date(input$rfs.period[1], unit = "month"):input$rfs.period[2] &
                                                 rin.melt$Fuel.Code %in% input$fuel.type,]) + 
          geom_line(aes(x = rin.date, y = value/1000000,  color = interaction(Fuel.Code, rf.metric))) + 
          labs(x = "", y = "Quantity (Millions)", title = title.text()) + 
          scale_color_manual(name = "D-Code", 
                             breaks = c("3.RIN.Quantity", "4.RIN.Quantity", "5.RIN.Quantity", "6.RIN.Quantity", "7.RIN.Quantity", "3.Batch.Volume", "4.Batch.Volume", "5.Batch.Volume", "6.Batch.Volume", "7.Batch.Volume"),
                             labels = c("D3 RINs", "D4 RINs", "D5 RINs", "D6 RINs", "D7 RINs", "D3 Batch Volume", "D4 Batch Volume", "D5 Batch Volume", "D6 Batch Volume", "D7 Batch Volume"),
                             values = tol12qualitative[1:(2*length(input$fuel.type))])+
          guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3))) + 
          facet_wrap(~Fuel.Code!=6, nrow = 2, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
          theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())
        }
      print(rf.rin.plot2)
      }
    }
    })
  })

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```